# MySQL and Java: Byte array not same when retrieved as it was when stored

Tags: java, mysql, hash, arrays

I'm creating a table for users containing their hashed passwords and it's salt.

The issue is that when I create the user's row in the table and save the salt and password (both are `byte[]` stored in `VARBINARY` columns) and try to get that data back when the user logs back in, the returned salt and hashed password is different than it was when I created the row.

To get the data I am using `ResultSet` and I call `resultSet.getBytes("password")`

To create the row I use a query like this (removed other column data to make it simpler):

```
String query = String.format("insert into users (`password`, `salt`) values ('%s','%s');", user.getHashedPassword(), user.getSalt());
```

Could there be some conversion or something that is happening that causes this problem? Should I be using something other than `VARBINARY` for storing `byte[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could there be some conversion or something that is happening that causes this problem?

Yes. You're basically calling `toString()` on a byte array. That isn't going to do what you want. Did you look at the SQL you were executing?

More than that, you shouldn't be producing a SQL string like this anyway - it's an approach which is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well as conversion issues.

Instead, use a `PreparedStatement` with parameterized SQL, and specify the parameter values directly (`PreparedStatement.setBytes` etc).

More broadly than that, it would be a good idea not to roll your own authentication code at all - look for an existing library that fits in well with whatever framework you're using, that's likely to avoid any of the numerous security vulnerabilities that it's all too easy to create when doing it yourself.

Comment: Ok, that looks like what I need. Also, what would you suggest for preventing injections. Would stripping escape characters be enough?

Comment: @vedi0boy: No, you use a `PreparedStatement` with parameterized SQL, as I said in the answer. When the parameter values are specified separately from the SQL, they don't need escaping.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I am asking. I'm not asking if I need to add escape characters. I am asking if I need to remove any. I did research on SQL injections and one of the biggest threats is hackers using escape characters to escape a String entry, such as username, and modify the query themselves. I am asking if using `str.replaceAll("\", "")` would be enough.

Comment: @vedi0boy: No, it wouldn't. Don't try to do this yourself with escaping. Just use parameterized SQL. It's superior in all ways.

Comment: @vedi0boy: Not typically, because it doesn't need to. From my earlier comment: "When the parameter values are specified separately from the SQL, they don't need escaping." Of course a particular implementation *might* format the values in the SQL and escape them, but usually the database provides a way of specifying the parameters in a different data stream. At that point they're *only* values.

Comment: Ok, so what I understand is: Using `PreparedStatement` will solve both my `byte[]` issue and also prevent injections.